# Some hyperlinks in Hugo are not correctly rendered

Tags: hyperlink, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I wrote a shortcode for Hugo:

```
# bottomlinks.html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
{{ with .Get "link-http" }}
<a href="{{ . }}">Link http</a>
{{ end }}
</td>
<td>
{{ with .Get "link-ftp" }}
<a href="{{ . }}">Link ftp</a>
{{ end }}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then in my "page.md" I added the following code

```
{{< bottomlinks link-http="https://test.com" link-ftp="ftp://test.com" >}}
```

Then I started Hugo 0.65.3.

The shortcode is correctly compiled into my website, but, while the http link is correctly recognized, the ftp link is strangely translated in the html code, something like "#ZhjkfdyuZ"

If I use the string instead

```
{{<bottomlinks link-http="https://test.com" link-ftp="http://test.com">}}
```

Both links are correctly recognized.

It seems that Hugo refuses to reproduce ftp links.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Hugo that the link is safe, by adding "| safeURL" in the markup.
See your shortcode below and the corresponding doc here: https://gohugo.io/functions/safeurl/

```
   # bottomlinks.html
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               {{ with .Get "link-http" }}
               <a href="{{ . }}">Link http</a>
               {{ end }}
           </td>
           <td>
               {{ with .Get "link-ftp" }}
               {{ . }}
               <a href="{{ . | safeURL }}">Link ftp</a>
               {{ end }}
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
```